# INNER JOIN to SELECT Statement

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have 2 tables, primary and secondary, with the same columns. They share a reference number with some duplicate entries and some unique to both. I am trying to query from them combined in such as way as to select all from the primary where ref is duplicative, then select all of the remaining from both.

This is what I have tried:

```
SELECT * FROM primary as p
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT * FROM primary WHERE ref NOT IN ( SELECT ref from secondary ) as s)
ON p.ref = s.ref
```

I get a syntax error that appears to be related to the last "ON p.ref = s.ref" part. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, of the code actually does what you try to achieve, but the syntax error is connected with the last closing bracket. Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM primary as p
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT * FROM primary WHERE ref NOT IN ( SELECT ref from secondary )) as s
ON p.ref = s.ref
```

Comment: That query provided a result, but not the one I wanted. It was helpful, however, as allowed me to get past the syntax error to then realize I was on the wrong track with INNER JOIN, that I instead should just use UNION. I've answer my question herein. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I was on the wrong track with INNER JOIN. Using UNION allowed me to get the result I was looking for.

```
SELECT * FROM primary
UNION
(SELECT * FROM secondary WHERE ref NOT IN ( SELECT ref from primary ))
```